# Unreferenced static inner classes treated differently by MOXy and the RI

Tags: java, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

Let's say I have the following two classes:

```
package example.model;

public class Model {
    public static class Inner {}

    public Other prop;
}
```

and

```
package example.model;

public class Other {
    public static class Inner {}

    public String prop;
}
```

and I create a JAXB context with `JAXBContext.newInstance(example.model.Model.class)`.

With the default JAXB implementation from Java 6 this works without any annotations, and a generated model does not mention *"inner"*. with EclipseLink I get a *"Name collision.  Two classes have the XML type with uri  and name inner."*

I know that making at least one of the inner classes @XmlTransient gets rid of the problem. What I would like to know is how this difference relates to the JAXB standard,
and, I guess, also if there is any other way to make MOXy ignore these classes like the default JAXB implementation does.

Comment: Sounds like a MOXy bug basically.

Comment: Could well be just a bug. If someone not unhappy with the JCP licenses confirms that this is the case, I'll go and report it.

Comment: I don't know what "not unhappy with the JCP licenses" means but I would report it anyway.

Comment: I believe @EJP is correct and that this is a bug in MOXy.  I have added an answer with more details:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/9726840/383861

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php).  We are currently working on a fix for the EclipseLink 2.3.3 and 2.4.0 streams.  You can track our progress using the following link:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/374429

Once the fix is available you will be able to download a nightly build from the following link:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php

**Workaround**

As you mention you can mark the static inner class with `@XmlTransient`.

```
package example.model;

public class Model {
    @XmlTransient        
    public static class Inner {}

    public Other prop;
}
```

Comment: The bug is already closed as fixed. Nice. Interestingly, the patch attached to the bug just removes a loop explicitly marked as `// handle inner classes`.